# How do I get rid of the "The Software on this Computer is up to date" message after updates?

Tags: update-manager, notification

I'm a bit annoyed by the Update Manager. Since I upgraded from 12.04 I get this message, after installing updates:

[image: Message after Updates were installed successfully]

I Find it utterly useless. It just another thing that pops in my face. If an update failed I get an error message regardless. It's interface 101 that you don't need a message when everything went well. How do I get rid of it or file a complaint so that it will not be included in future versions?

I know this is a minor thing but for some reason it really annoys me.

Update: [Launchpad Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1072100)

Comment: I know that you can do almost everything with Open Source applications. Take the code of Update Manager , edit it and create .deb packages and install it. Do not expect from me to do this because I don't know :p , but I know that you can modify almost everything in Open Source.

Comment: Sure a patch should be enough. That however has two drawbacks: 1. This way it will not reach users quiet that well. 2. One has to redo the work every time Update manager gets updated itself. The better solution in my eyes would be to fix this from the official side.

Comment: For the 1st (about users quiet) , yes I accept that. The 2nd (redo the work every time) this can be overcome with the pin of Update-manager from update itself. You can pin any program you want. If you want an official-side solution then consider to open a bug or something.

Comment: A pin would compromise security as the Update manager is a vital program to Ubuntu and gets root privileges on a regular basis. How ever I will consider making a patch when I have the time. An idea on Ubuntu Brainstorm posted as this technically does not constitute a bug.

Comment: The LaunchPad bug has expired. Is the correct action here to open a new bug and link to the old one?

Comment: Well, I unexpired it, I still think it is valid.

Comment: Now it's even worse, it has an ad on it (for livepatch).

Answer (score 0):

You can disable automatic software update check by setting "Automatically check for update" to never in the drop-down in the updates tab of Software and update settings. Here is the full guide: https://www.garron.me/en/linux/turn-off-stop-ubuntu-automatic-update.html

Then when you want to update your packages use a command.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y dist-upgrade
```

You can even use an alias to make things easier. Below is what I'm using in my `.bashrc` file.

```
alias aptupgrade="sudo apt update && sudo apt -y dist-upgrade"
```